# Kivy & Python: How to fill canvas with an image multiple times during one app run?

Tags: python, numpy, kivy, python-imaging-library

I'm creating an app that has sth like basic Paint in it. I can save output as .png, do stuff with it and save data matrix that I get to another .png file. After that I'm trying to fill the Paint area with that image using that function:

```
    def paint_solution(self, img):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(source=img, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

This all stuff is getting done after pressing "start" button.
I also has "clear" button that is clearing canvas space: `self.canvas.clear()`.

When I paint sth, use "start" everything works fine. The problem is: When I press "clear" button and try to do it again it shows me the first image, despite that the image in folder is updated.
I've tried to put sleep() between saving and displaying image:

```
img = Image.fromarray(data_matrix) #data_matrix is ndarray; Image is from PIL
img.save("sol.png")
sleep(1.0)
self.paint.paint_solution()
```

I've tried it up to 10 sec and it's not working.
I'm making this app with kivy.

EDIT: I've tried sleep(45.0) and it works. Does someone know how to make it shorter?

**SOLUTION**: @John Anderson 's solution was not working for me, I've got:

> Rectangle(texture=CoreImage.load(img, nocache=True).texture, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'

But it helped me to got this solution, which is approximately the same thing:

```
    def paint_solution(self, img):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            sol = Image(source=img)
            sol.reload()
            Rectangle(texture=sol.texture, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

The `sol.reload()` and `texture=sol.texture` are crucial.

Comment: Kivy is caching the image. I'm not sure offhand what the easiest way to refresh the cache is, but it's definitely possible. Possibly `Image` has an `upadate` method or something similar for it.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the comment from @inclement, I think it will work as you want by using `texture` instead of `source`, like this:

```
def paint_solution(self):
    self.canvas.clear()
    with self.canvas:
        Rectangle(texture=CoreImage.load('sol.png', nocache=True).texture, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

The `nocache=True` is the key.